# Update table based on Month from another table

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables in a MySQL database that are dependent on each other.
Currently the **DateExpires** field in `Table 2` needs to be a date formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s`
But I’m trying to get it to be one year and on the first day from the **DateJoined** field or the Renewal Month field in `Table1`, like: `2014-03-01 12:00:00`

I’ve been trying to Update them based on the **Renewal Month** and the **DateJoined** field but nothing gives me the result im looking for, how can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.  You're going to do an update, joining the two tables (1 and 2) along with a derived table of month names to map to a month number.  You're setting `t2.DateExpires` to a concatenation of values from the join.

Here's a demo of it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a388d/1

```
UPDATE `Table1` AS `t1`
    INNER JOIN `Table2` AS `t2` 
        ON `t2`.`IDMember` = `t1`.`ID`
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT '01' AS `number`, 'Jan' AS `name`
        UNION SELECT '02', 'Feb'
        UNION SELECT '03', 'Mar'
        UNION SELECT '04', 'Apr'
        UNION SELECT '05', 'May'
        UNION SELECT '06', 'Jun'
        UNION SELECT '07', 'Jul'
        UNION SELECT '08', 'Aug'
        UNION SELECT '09', 'Sep'
        UNION SELECT '10', 'Oct'
        UNION SELECT '11', 'Nov'
        UNION SELECT '12', 'Dec'
    ) AS `m` ON `m`.`name` = `t1`.`RenewalMonth`
SET `t2`.`DateExpires` = CONCAT(
                    IF(YEAR(`t1`.`DateJoined`), YEAR(`t1`.`DateJoined`), YEAR(NOW())) + 1, 
                    '-', `m`.`number`, '-01 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Well, ran into a bit of trouble, it also seems to update some records as `0001-01-01 12:00:00` instead of an actual date.

Comment: Do you have any records where `DateJoined` is null?

Comment: Added a `COALESCE` to handle `NULL` values in `DateJoined` (filling in with current year in those cases)

Comment: Ah, It's my mistake, some `DateJoined` fields had '0000-00-00', Thanks!

Comment: Oops - one last edit... forgot a `YEAR()` function on `NOW()`

Answer (score 1):

Use DATE_ADD to add a year, and DATE_FORMAT to convert to the desired format:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET DateExpires = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(t1.DateJoined, 'INTERVAL 1 YEAR'), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') 
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE IDMember = t1.ID
```

If you want to base this on RenewalMonth, you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET DateExpires = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(
   concat(t1.RenewalMonth, ' ', 
          DAY(t1.DateJoined), ', ',
          YEAR(t1.DateJoined)), '%M %d,%Y'), 
   'INTERVAL 1 YEAR'), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') 
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE IDMember = t1.ID
```

Comment: He doesn't want to simply add a year.  He wants "Renewal Month" of the next year.

Comment: There's no way you can be sure based on the question that `RenewalDate` is `%M`.

Comment: @StevenMoseley - you assumed that it was when you built your derived table :).  And I think that's a pretty safe assumption.

Comment: Yeah, but I did it that way because a derived table can be edited if the values aren't right.  A function can't.

Comment: But +1 anyway, because this is a useful solution for someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update table2 as t2 
inner join table1 as t1 on t2.IDMember = t1.ID 
set DateExpires = date_format(date_add(t1.DateJoined, 'interval 1 year'), '%Y-%m-%d 12:00:00')
```